# How do find a element that is less then another element?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set up a Binary search program that uses strings instead of integers. Problem is that I don't know how to make an array of numbers that are less then a string value.

For example

string array less than string value.

```
/**
   The StringBinarySearcher class provides a public static
   method for performing a binary search on an String array.
*/



public class StringBinarySearcher
{
   /**
      The search method performs a binary search on an String
      array. The array is searched for the number passed to
      value. If the number is found, its array subscript is
      returned. Otherwise, -1 is returned indicating the
      value was not found in the array.
      @param numbers The array to search.
      @param value The value to search for.
   */



   public static int search(String[] numbers, String value)
   {
      int first;       // First array element
      int last;        // Last array element
      int middle;      // Mid point of search
      int position;    // Position of search value
      boolean found;   // Flag

      // Set the inital values.
      first = 0;
      last = numbers.length - 1;
      position = -1;
      found = false;

      // Search for the value.
      while (!found && first <= last)
      {
         // Calculate mid point
         middle = (first + last) / 2;

         // If value is found at midpoint...
         if (numbers[middle] == value)
         {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
         }

         // else if value is in lower half...
         // needs array to be less then the string value?, without using equality regulators
         else if (numbers[middle].compareTo(numbers[middle +1]) > 0)
            last = middle - 1;
         // else if value is in upper half....
         else
            first = middle + 1;
      }

      // Return the position of the item, or -1
      // if it was not found.
      return position;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need an array of numbers to do binary search on your array of strings?

Comment: BTW, `if (numbers[middle] == value)` is wrong comparison, use `if (numbers[middle].equals(value))`

Comment: Can sort strings numberical, with out integers?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comparison:

```
if (numbers[middle] == value)
```

should **not** use the `==` operator.  Remember you're comparing String objects.  You should either use the [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method or [`compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

The next comparison you have is:

```
// else if value is in lower half...
// needs array to be less then the string value?, without using equality regulators
else if (numbers[middle].compareTo(numbers[middle +1]) > 0)
```

According to your comments  you're checking to see if `value` is in the lower half of the array, but your code is comparing an array element to the next array element.  To match the comments it should be:

```
else if (value.compareTo(numbers[middle]) < 0)
```

Also, please note that you will get some strange looking results when comparing Strings that represent numbers the way you're doing.  The `compareTo` method compares Strings lexicographically.  This means, for example, that "5" will evaluate to be greater than "11".

Comment: else if (value.compareTo(numbers[middle]) < 0) wouldn't that compare only one element that is less than value.

Comment: @user663428: That will return 'true' if the `value` is (alphabetically) less than the middle element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the comparison operator (==).  The comparison operator is only well defined for primitive data types in Java.  String is a class (not a primitive data type).  Therefore, you will need to use String's `equals(String)` method to compare them.

If you want to compare them as numbers, then you will need to parse them into Integers.  For this, you can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` and then compare the Integers.

Comment: Okay i forgot about that, I should of know better.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for primitive data type. Not for String objects.

== is used to check whether the reference of two objects are same or not. "==" never compares the content of two objects.

```
String strName1 = "Me";
String strName2 = new String("Me");
```

`strName1 == strName2` is false. Since they are referring to two different objects.

You can use equals method to do comparison.

```
if (strName2 .equals(strName2 )) {
    System.out.println("Me and Me are same :P");
}
```